# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to manage the users roles using firebase auth and firestore but when i try to pass the `snapshot.data` to the class i create to save the user date in firestore i got this error. i followed a tutorial but my code is different and I'm using a newer version.

```
class Start extends StatelessWidget {
  const Start({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
          UserHelper.saveUser(snapshot.data!);
          return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(snapshot.data!.uid)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              final user = snapshot.data?.data();
              if ((user as Map<String, dynamic>)['role'] == 'admin') {
                return const Home();
              } else {
                return const UserHome();
              }
            },
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(child: Text('Algo ha salido mal!'));
        } else {
          return const LoginScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a stream of nullable User type `Stream<User?> authStateChanges()`

You should cast away nullability with `!` operator:
`UserHelper.saveUser(snapshot.data!)`, this is safe to do since you have `snapshot.data!=null` check in the if clause

As a side note, you might want to reconsider your business logic. `authStateChanges()` will not be fired on user profile (name, email) changes, but you do update those in the downstream call. `userChanges()` will be fired on those changes, but if you subscribe to that stream then you dont need to always update `last_login`. see https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/start/#userchanges

Comment: Thanks i didn't set the <User?> in the StreamBuilder that was the error, as i said i was following a tutorial very old maybe that was the error maybe that is the reason of the authStateChange( ), my english and knowledge about flutter are pretty lame so i don't understand de UserChanges( ) thing

Comment: Can you help me with the null safe error please i edited the post

Comment: @WilldersCarvajal which error do you need help with? After you edited the post I dont see where is the error

Answer (score 0):

Your method:

```dart
static saveUser(User user) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
      "name": user.displayName,
      "email": user.email,
      "last_login": user.metadata.lastSignInTime,
      "created_at": user.metadata.creationTime,
      "role": "user",
    };
```

accepts a `User`, but you're passing to it the `snapshot.data`:

```dart
UserHelper.saveUser(snapshot.data);
```

Which definitely isn't a `User`.

You probably want a `fromJson` method on your `User` class that will convert the JSON to a `User`. It can look like this, for example:

```dart
class User {
  String id;
  String name;
  User({required this.id, required this.name});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

And then you would call it:

```dart
UserHelper.saveUser(User.fromJson(snapshot.data()!));
```